# Calculate row difference within groups

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for help with calculating the difference between consecutive ordered rows within groups in SQL (Microsoft SQL server).

I have a table like this:

```
ID   School_ID   Enrollment_Start_Date   Order
1        56            1/1/2018            10
1        56            5/5/2018            24
1        56            7/7/2018            35  
1       103            4/4/2019            26
1       103            3/3/2019            19
```

I want to calculate the difference between Order, **group by** ID, School_ID, and  **order by** Enrollment_Start_Date.

so I want something like this:

```
ID   School_ID   Enrollment_Start_Date   Order  Diff
1        56            1/1/2018            10    10 # nothing to be subtracted from 10
1        56            5/5/2018            24    14 # 24-10
1        56            7/7/2018            35    11 # 35-24
1       103            3/3/2019            19    19 # nothing to be subtracted from 19
1       103            4/4/2019            26    7 # 26-19
```

I have hundreds of IDs, and each ID can have at most 6 Enrollment_Start_Date, so I'm looking for some generalizable implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LAG(<column>)` analytic function to obtain a "previous" column value specified within the `OVER` part, then substract current value from it and make it a positive number multiplying it by `-1`. If previous value isn't present (is null) then take the current value.

**Pseudo code would be:**

```
If previous_order_value exists:
  -1 * (previous_order_value - current_order_value)
Else
  current_order_value
```

where previous_order_value is based on the same id & school_id and is sorted by enrollment_start_date in ascending order

**SQL Code:**

```
select
    id,
    school_id,
    enrollment_start_date,
    [order],
    coalesce(-1 * (lag([order]) over (partition by id, school_id order by enrollment_start_date ) - [order]), [order]) as diff
from yourtable
```

Also note, that `order` keyword is reserved in SQL Server, which is why your column was created with name wrapped within `[ ]`. I suggest using some other word for this column, if possible.

Comment: this is the perfect solution, thanks @Kamil Gosciminski

Comment: @Zoe I've modified the code by adding `coalesce` to address the problem when previous value isn't present - now it will show current value instead of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

use `lag()` analytic function for getting difference of two row  and case when for getting orginal value of order column where no difference exist

```
    with cte as
(
select 1 as id, 56 as sclid, '2018-01-01' as s_date, 10 as orders
union all
select 1,56,'2018-05-05',24 union all
select 1,56,'2018-07-07',35 union all
select 1,103,'2019-04-04',26 union all
select 1,103,'2019-03-03',19 
) select t.*, 
case when ( lag([orders])over(partition by id,sclid order by s_date ) -[orders] )
 is null then [orders] else
  ( lag([orders])over(partition by id,sclid order by s_date ) -[orders] )*(-1) end
  as diff
 from cte t
```

output

```
id  sclid   s_date   orders diff
1    56   2018-01-01    10  10
1    56   2018-05-05    24  14
1    56   2018-07-07    35  11
1    103  2019-03-03    19  19
1   103   2019-04-04    26  7
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=714f70bf135bd812f27ef613902d975a)

Comment: Thank you @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin

Answer (score 0):

Use LAG(COLUMN_NAME)

**Query**

```
SELECT id, School_ID, Enrollment_Start_Date, cOrder,
ISNULL((cOrder - (LAG(cOrder) OVER(PARTITION BY id, School_ID ORDER BY Enrollment_Start_Date))),cOrder)Diff
FROM Table1
```

**Samle Output**

```
| id | School_ID | Enrollment_Start_Date | cOrder | Diff |
|----|-----------|-----------------------|--------|------|
|  1 |        56 |            2018-01-01 |     10 |   10 |
|  1 |        56 |            2018-05-05 |     24 |   14 |
|  1 |        56 |            2018-07-07 |     35 |   11 |
|  1 |       103 |            2019-03-03 |     19 |   19 |
|  1 |       103 |            2019-04-04 |     26 |    7 |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ba5bc/4)